# No new or edited answers after a bounty?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, bounties

I created a bounty on a question not my own. But since then there has been no updates and I'm still having the problem. There still is no accepted answer either. I'd rather have my reputation disappear then award it to the highest answer since there has been no effort done at all and I'm still left with the issue.

My feature request would be to not award the bounty if there has been no activity at all since the bounty start. Perhaps award it if someone at least attempted to improve it's answer. And perhaps refund the bounty, or have it extended for X days.

Comment: I guess you have discovered something even so... that your question may be too hard or obscure for anyone to answer.

Comment: That feature already exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My feature request would be to not award the bounty if there has been no activity at all since the bounty start.

This is already the case.

The bounty is only automatically awarded to a qualifying answer if that answer was posted *after* the bounty was started.

So if there are no new answers, or the any new answers are scoring less than 2 then the bounty will expire without being awarded. The only way it can get awarded in this case is if you award it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Will the advertisement company return your money if nobody bought your product that was advertised? No.

The same is true for bounties: it is 'advertisement money', not a guarantee for answers. Changing that wouldn't be fair. Refunding is not going to happen.

As explained in my comments, the bounty will not be automatically awarded to answers that were placed before the bounty started. So the feature you requested is already there.

I would advise you to check your question to check if it is really good to understand and answer. If not, edit it. If it is, maybe the question is just too hard to answer.

Comment: But would the advertisement company pay all the people who did not help advertising the product? I'm not asking for a refund per se, it's optional and open for discussion if and only `IF` there has been no activity between start and end of the bounty.

Comment: SE is advertising your question by putting it on the featured tab.

Comment: And it is going to pay the people that did not help by automatically dividing my bounty between the highest voted answers. So all those people get free rep for doing nothing extra.

Comment: No. Existing answers do not get the bounty awarded automatically.

Comment: [Then someone update the docs please](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/bounty). It states the bounty gets divided if no answer is voted accepted. And thus people get free reputation. I'm fine with losing my bounty for advertisement sake, I'm just not fine with people getting the reputation for doing nothing.

Comment: *If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created **after the bounty started** with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.*

Comment: It says it all. The answer must be created in the bounty period to be qualified for awarding automatically.

Comment: TIFU by not reading correctly. Thanks for spelling it out for me.